# What is equivalent of SIPAddHeader UNI: in PJSIP

Tags: asterisk, voip

I am converting one script, where I see following agi call

```
$agi->exec("SIPAddHeader","UNI: X-$UNIQUESIPHEADER")
```

I tried web but don't understand what is the purpose of this header and what would be its alternate in PJSIP_HEADER, as it is actualy just setting unique id in MD5 values.

Comment: Are you asking of how to add the header, or what the header does? I don't recognize the header. I guess that it was added to track your calls with some system.

Comment: In my our old AGI we have this added defined, but now I updated to latest version but can't get any idea what it does? as I don't find any other reference of it in the script.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no standard purpose of that header. It is a custom header, added by someone to track something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older API this function was being used create a Unique ID but in my case I don't need to create any id, as my PJSIP script on asterisk 16 working great and it is saving everything perfectly. This header is used if you need to create any unique id or something for any specific purpose. But if you are saving simple cdrs, there is no need of it.